# VBA Runtime Error 13 because of wrong Format

Tags: vba

I want to add a product number to a collection like this:

```vb
colData.Add marke.Value + " " + pn.Value (Range-Objekte)
```

Every time I start the macro it runs in Runtime Error 13.

If the product number is like 256-78979-0980 everything runs fine.
If the product number is like 8898686 the error occurs.

Writing `CStr(pn.Value)` doesn't solve the issue.

The only solution I found is to change the format of all PNs to type text.
Then I need to go in the cell and press "Enter" after that a sign appears on the cell stating that the number is recognized as text.
After that the macro works fine for this cell but not for the others.

How can I change my data to make it work with my macro?

Comment: `How can I change my data` - https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `+` for concatenation.

Try repalcing of

```
colData.Add marke.Value + " " + pn.Value
```

with

```
colData.Add marke.Value & " " & pn.Value
```

Comment: As a matter of fact the use of ampersand is the right syntax of concationation in vb classic (vb, vb script and vba)

Comment: Thanks for the tip but the problem still occurs